# What is this rubbish I find when I open iMovie with script editor?

Tags: applescript, symbols

So I was just messing around with script editor to try some apple-scripting. So then I thought of opening iMovie with script editor so I could save it as a tweaked version of iMovie but when I tried opening iMovie with script editor, it gave me this:

œ˙Ì˛Ä)ÿÖ H__PAGEZERO__TEXTpp__text__TEXTxOÄ__stubs__TEXTxlLxlÄ__stub_helper__TEXTƒq‰ƒqÄ__const__TEXT∞z∞z__objc_methname__TEXT¿àf!¿à__cstring__TEXT&™w€&™__objc_classname__TEXTùÖùÖ__objc_methtype__TEXT∞£ºX∞£__ustring__TEXTl¸Xl¸__gcc_except_tab__TEXTƒ¸ú(ƒ¸__unwind_info__TEXT`%@6`%__eh_frame__TEXT†[X†[à__DATAp`pP__nl_symbol_ptr__DATApp‚__got__DATApHp‰__la_symbol_ptr__DATAX|X|m__mod_init_func__DATAhÉhÉ    __const__DATApÉ@ pÉ__cfstring__DATA∞£ ø∞£__objc_classlist__DATA–bP–b__objc_catlist__DATA kh k__objc_protolist__DATAàkàk__objc_imageinfo__DATAxmxm__objc_const__DATAÄm`Äm__objc_selrefs__DATA‡âXå‡â__objc_protorefs__DATA8 8__objc_classrefs__DATAX∏X__objc_superrefs__DATA%`%__objc_ivar__DATAp+†$p+__objc_data__DATAP SP__data__DATA0£ê0£__bss__DATA¿º†__common__DATA`¬H__LINKEDIT–¿  ¿Pπ "Ä0¿®,®Ïp}j»‡Éòµ UÂ ¨p@ëP##ó∫+pcO /usr/lib/dyld#€"ƒÊ6TûŸπwëí¬+$

And that is only like 1/1000 of the script. So out of curiosity, can someone please explain to me what this and if there is a way to translate this?


[Click here to view the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ff5y.png)

Comment: There's a difference between AppleScript and a compiled binary program. iMovie is an example of the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMovie (along with most other applications) are not written in AppleScript, but are built by compiling many source files (such as Objective-C or Swift) and assets, then assembling the various pieces with a build system.  In Apple’s setup all that is performed by Xcode.  Like baking a cake, once compiled, it is very difficult to extract the original ingredients from the finished product.

It looks like you opened a binary file with TextEdit (the Script Editor won’t open those), but you will also get a bunch of rubbish opening a `.scpt` file in TextEdit, since those are also compiled (to an intermediate code).  As you have seen, the text representation of a script is different than the compiled version that is saved in a script file, which is also different than a binary executable file.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can somehow translate this?

Comment: Not really. As mentioned, the file you are looking at is a compiled binary executable file, and although it may contain some readable symbols (strings, method names, etc) it is not a script that you can just drop into a code editor.